# How to find an element (dict) of a nested dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

I want to find an element of my nested dictionnary. The element I want is also a dictionnary. I try this function which use recursivity:

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
```

This is my dictionnary :

```
nest_dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":{the dict i want} } } }
```

I loop through my generator :

```
for my_element in find('c', nest_dict):
    print(my_element)
```

The problem is that when I print **my_element**, it contains all the content of the **nest_dict** in a dict of 1 element and not just each element of it.

Thx.

PS : sorry for my english

Comment: That's not even a valid dict syntax.

Comment: Ignoring the bad syntax for your example dict and your code, the simplest way to get the desired nested dictionary is to apply get 3 times to it. In your simple case, assuming you want the dictionary associated to key "c" all you need to do is nested_dict.get('a').get('b').get('c')

Comment: The output looks correct to me. Can you show us the output you're getting and the output you expected to get?

Answer (score 0):

First of all as mentioned by @Ashwini Chaudhary and @BoboDarph your dictionary syntax is not valid to do what you are asking you can do the following:

```
nest_dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":'the dict i want' } } }

print nest_dict['a']['b']['c']
```

**output:**

```
the dict i want
```